# Getting information from the join table in a has many through query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Imagine 3 models: User, Club and UserClub.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :clubs,
           through: :user_clubs

  has_many :user_clubs
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users,
           through: :user_clubs

  has_many :user_clubs
end

class UserClub < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club
end
```

Very typical join table stuff.

Now, imagine a scenario where you want to retrieve one user's clubs **and** the amount of users that are in each club.

In a controller, retrieving a users clubs is simple:

```
def index
  @clubs = current_user.clubs

  #do whatever you will with them
end
```

The second part puzzles me though as I don't know how to do it as efficiently as possible.

Sure, I could do something like this:

```
def index
  @clubs = current_user.clubs

  @no_of_users_per_club = Hash.new(0)

  @clubs.each do |club|

    @no_of_users_per_club[club.id] = UserClub.where(club_id: club.id).count

  end

  #Do whatever you would do after
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? It would be a tad redundant, but ultimately, maybe the best solution is to simply store that integer as an attribute of each network, so that when a user joins a club, I increment it by one and when a user leaves a club, I decrease it by one?

**UPDATE: The selected answer below shows a very cool way to do it and an even cooler way to limit the results to just your clubs.**

```
@no_of_user_per_club_of_mine = UserClub.
                                       joins("INNER JOIN user_clubs AS uc ON user_clubs.club_id = uc.club_id").
                                       where("uc.user_id = ?" , current_user.id).
                                       group("user_clubs.club_id").
                                       count("user_clubs.user_id")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can use `group` to retrieve the `count` of `users` in each `club` directly from the join model 'TableClub'.

```
@no_of_users_per_club = UserClub.group(:club_id).count(:user_id)
# => {1=>1, 2=>5, 3=>8}
```

#### To get the number of users in each club, where these clubs are joined by current_user:

```
@no_of_user_per_club_of_mine = UserClub.joins("INNER JOIN user_clubs AS uc ON user_clubs.club_id = uc.club_id").where("uc.user_id = ?" , current_user.id).group("user_clubs.club_id").count("user_clubs.user_id")
```

Comment: Oh wow, this seems like it would easily solve the problem. I'm assuming this gives you a hash where the key is the club_id, and the value is the number of user_ids associated with it? Namely, the amount of users per club?

Comment: Is there any way to have it be a model object pointing to the count instead of the club_id?

Comment: Eh, it's okay. Right now I'm doing something like this:

    `user_counts = Userclub.group(:club_id).count(:user_id);`

    `clubs = current_user.clubs.to_a;`

    `clubs_and_count = clubs.map { |club|
      [club, user_count[club.id]]
    }`

Is there a better way to encapsulate the relation?

Comment: please add that to your question, it would be better for the community. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @count = current_user.user_clubs.group_by{|o|o.club_id}.map{|k,v|[k, v.first.club.users.length]}
 This will return a array of array which contain club_id at first index and count of users related to this club at second index

 @count.length will return total clubs related to current user
```